# Query ColdFusion Externally

Tags: forms, coldfusion

Is it possible to submit a query to a form built with ColdFusion from a page built on another site. The form I have in mind is this one.. http://web.sba.gov/pro-net/search/dsp_dsbs.cfm

I'd like to build a page on my site with its own version of that form and when users click submit have it pass the information to the site above and load the search results based off of their selections. Essentially just creating a different set of controls for it. I just wasn't sure if this was even possible.

Comment: Sounds possible to me.  I recommend giving it a shot.

Comment: I'd like to, I just wasn't sure if I was chasing ghosts. I don't know a whole lot about ColdFusion but I'm trying to learn. Anyone know what language the form on my site should be written in for this to work? I'll start trying things out and doing some research.

Comment: Simple html would do the trick if you're posting to an external site.

Comment: Assuming you simply want to display the results from the other site on a page in the other site, what others have offered will work. However, if you want to query the data and display the data on your site..well...that is quite a different beast. If there is no API, then it would not be an easy task and any way to accomplish this without an API would likely be a violation of the terms of use of the site from which you are trying to get the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Submitting a HTML form simply composes a GET/POST request (depending on the `method` attribute in your `form`) and sends it to the URL stated in the `action` attribute in your `form`. The URL can be any resource and is **not** restricted to the same origin.

Edit: If you simply want to host a form on your own site, just make sure to keep the field names, form action and form method.

You can handle the GET/POST request the same way you would do it on your own page. In ColdFusion the form fields would be available in the `URL` scope (when `<form method="get">`) or in the `FORM` scope (when `<form method="post">`).